# How does concurrent access to Xodus via MVCC work

Tags: xodus

Xodus doc states it provides MVCC. This indicates, that it can be accessed concurrently.
On the other hand doc for class Environment states: "It is not possible to share a single database directory between different environments."

Which is true? Can I access a Xodus database in read-only mode while it is open for some other process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xodus is an embeddable database for JVM, so it can be accessed concurrently within a single process. As of now, development of [concurrent access to a Xodus database from within multiple processes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-613) is in progress.

Comment: The Issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-613 status now is re-opened does it mean that there have been issues with accessing Xodus concurrently from different processes? My setup of Xodus is that the servlet runs on NGINX Unit which spawns multiple instances of the server application but in the same machine.

Comment: XD-613 is most likely obsolete as now we go the other way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995773/multiple-xodus-app-to-access-share-single-directory/57003792#57003792